# local yeoman generator not found by yo

Tags: node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I created a new yeoman generator

```
'use strict';

var generators = require('yeoman-generator');

module.exports = generators.Base.extend({
  method1: function() {
    this.log('Hello, World!');
  }
});
```

My `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "generator-mygenerator",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Alexander Zeitler",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "yeoman-generator": "^0.22.5"
  }
}
```

Then I ran `npm link`

When calling `yo mygenerator` I get this error:

```
Error mygenerator 

You don't seem to have a generator with the name mygenerator installed.
You can see available generators with npm search yeoman-generator and then install them with npm install [name].
To see the 1 registered generators run yo with the `--help` option.
```

I also tried `npm link generator-mygenerator`.

Node.js version `4.2.3` and npm version `3.7.5`.
I installed Node.js using `nvm`

`yo doctor` results in this:

```
Yeoman Doctor
Running sanity checks on your system

✔ Global configuration file is valid
✔ Node.js version
✔ No .bowerrc file in home directory
✔ No .yo-rc.json file in home directory
✔ npm version
✔ NODE_PATH matches the npm root

Everything looks all right!
```

Answer (score 1):

The `index.js` has to be inside the `app` folder. It was in the project root folder instead.